# Unable to change data type of Cassandra column

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

For this table

```
mytable(
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    before_creation_hour int,
   ... creation_hour bigint,
...)
```

when I try to change type of `before_creation_hour`, I get error

```
cqlsh:codingjedi> alter table mytable
              ... alter before_creation_hour type bigint;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Altering of types is not allowed"`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Support for `ALTER TYPE` was dropped a number of years ago in Cassandra 3.0.11 and 3.10 ([CASSANDRA-12443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12443)) because it causes a lot of issues including nodes unable to start when replaying commitlog mutations for columns whose type was changed.

This is the reason you get the error message `Altering of types is not allowed`. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `int` cannot be changed to `bigint`. - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility